# SFML with VS 2015, cannot open include file

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, sfml

I'm trying to learn sfml, but I am having trouble getting started :/ It won't build in debug x64. I'm using windows 10.

my code (Win32 Console):

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

int main()
{
sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(200, 200), "SFML works!");
sf::CircleShape shape(100.f);
shape.setFillColor(sf::Color::Green);

while (window.isOpen())
{
    sf::Event event;
    while (window.pollEvent(event))
    {
        if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
            window.close();
    }

    window.clear();
    window.draw(shape);
    window.display();
}

return 0;
}
```

Properties that I've set:

general->Include Directories: I've set the sfml "include" dir here.

general->Library Directories: I've set this to "lib".

c/C++->General->additional include libraries: "include" like above.

linker->general->additional library directories: "lib" like above.

linker->input->additional dependencies: I listed out the 5 libs for release and debug separately.

I have also placed the debug "bin" sfml dlls in the debug folder.

I keep getting C1083 when I try to compile. And on my previous two attempts, I kept getting LNK2019 even though I'm pretty sure I've done nothing different.

What am I doing wrong? Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: setting general include and lib directory should be enough, no need to set additional. I'm pretty sure that your include path is not quite right

Comment: You can for example put the sfml folder in your solution folder and set the include path as $(SolutionDir)SFML\include\  this should work for your code

Comment: @FamZ I used the selection. I didn't type out the address. And I did put the dirs in the solution path, so... no one really knows? This is a first

Comment: For the include files there can't be any other reason other than a typo in the path, even if you downloaded the wrong version (32 bit instead of 64 bit) because the include folder is the same for both architectures and configurations(Debug/Release) or you did set the path on some other configuration, for example, you've set it on Release, but not on Debug

Comment: or you've set the paths for the 32 bit configuration but not for the 64 bit

Comment: @FamZ I don't know what's up. I followed all of the steps and got it working on my older machine that still runs 2013. There appears to be no differences in instructions between 2013 and 2015 installation so, does that give you any clues?

Comment: No, as you said, there shouldn't be any differences between the two versions.